# A Soviet Satire of War of the Worlds?

Tags: story-identification, translation, war-of-the-worlds

According to Wikipedia, Russian author Laza Lagin wrote a sequel to, possibly a satire of, H.G. Wells' *War of the Worlds*.

> In 1962, Soviet author Lazar Lagin published a political pamphlet named "Major Well Andyou" ("Майор Велл Эндъю"), a pun on "Well, and you?", which relates the story of a major in the British Army who collaborates with the Martian invaders. A condemnation of imperialism and capitalism, the story was dominated by Soviet analysis of political issues contemporary to the 1950s and 1960s.
>   <sub>—*Wikipedia*, ["List of works based on The War of the Worlds: Sequels by other authors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_based_on_The_War_of_the_Worlds#Sequels_by_other_authors)</sub>

and

> His novella Major Well Andyou (Майор Велл Эндъю) is a satiric sequel to H. G. Wells' The War of the Worlds.
>   <sub>—*Wikipedia*, ["Lazar LAgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazar_Lagin)</sub>

I'm curious to learn what the story is about; is there an English translation or synopsis to be found somewhere?

Comment: What's your question exactly? It's very unclear. If your question is "can someone give me a synopsis", that's probably very broad and subjective. If the story has an English title, can't you try to find the translated version?

Comment: A synopsis would be great or a link to English version; mainly interested in the traitor aspect -- is the traitor a Martian or a human is what I wonder.

Comment: @Jeff I've edited your question to better fit what you seem to want to know. Please roll back if it's not what you had in mind.

Comment: You may also be interested in *The Second Invasion from Mars* by Strugatsky brothers ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Second_Invasion_from_Mars ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [fantlab.ru](https://fantlab.ru/work55612), a Russian website that is a sort of encyclopaedia of fiction, the work is intended as an "afterword" to *The War of the Worlds*. Here is their synopsys, and my translation:

> Памфлет Л. Лагина «Майор Велл Эндью, его наблюдения, переживания, мысли, надежды и далеко идущие планы, записанные им в течение последних пятнадцати дней его жизни» как бы продолжает роман Г. Уэллса «Война миров». Офицер английских войск, убеждённый в непобедимости агрессоров-марсиан, чтобы не погибнуть, готов стать их прислужником. Своё предательство он пытается оправдать приспособленческой философией.

> The pamphlet of L. Lagin *Major Well Andyou, his observations, worries, thoughts, hopes, and far-stretching plans, recorded by him in the last 15 days of his life* is a continuation of sorts to H. G. Wells' *The War of the Worlds*. An officer of English military, convinced in the invincibility of Martian aggressors, is ready to become their servant in order to stay alive. He tries to explain his treachery using an "adaptability" philosophy.

Or from his [Russian Wikipedia page](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (translation also mine; his [English page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazar_Lagin) does not contain this):

> Особняком стоит сильная и острая повесть «Майор Велл Эндъю» (1962), своеобразное дополнение к «Войне миров» Г. Уэллса, посвящённая проблеме коллаборационизма.
>
> A separate place should be reserved for *Major Well Andyou* (1962), a sort of an addition to *The War of the Worlds* by H. G. Wells, devoted to the problem of [collaborationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborationism).

The website lists this work as a part of an [informal "cycle"](https://fantlab.ru/work55287) of works further exploring the ideas of H. G. Wells. The story is widely available in Russian online, e.g. [here](http://lib.ru/LAGIN/marsiane.txt) and [here](http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/add-on/xussr_l/laginl15.htm?1/8). Sadly, an English translation does not seem to exist.

<sub>I will try to read the piece and provide a synopsis here, but I can't promise I'll do it this week.</sub>

Comment: Thanks much, I think this is enough for now! I am guessing that the pun is based on Wells' name? Or is this a different pun based on Russian? Or not a pun at all?

Comment: @Jeff It reads like a pun on "Well, and you?", as in "How are you?" "Well, and you?"

Comment: @Jeff It does not appear to be a pun in Russian, except that I almost took it for a misspelled "Andrew".

Comment: Yes, exactly and I am wondering if this is "funny" because of Wells' name. To a Russian with some knowledge of English this might be very clever.